# How to remove title 'Navigation' from Navigation menu in Drupal 7?

Tags: theming, routes

How to remove title 'Navigation' from Navigation menu in the left column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can click "edit block" or go to the Blocks administration page and enter '<none>' for block title for the Navigation block.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 has a check box right under Block title, allowing you deselect it and not show the block title.

[image: Deselect show block title, Drupal 8]